# Does JMeter have "User-Defined Data Point Graphs" like LoadRunner?

Tags: graph, charts, jmeter, time-series, loadrunner

I am looking for a feature in Apache JMeter. I need the equivalent feature that I use with MicroFocus LoadRunner called "User-Defined Data Point Graphs".

From LR User Guide

> The User-Defined Data Point graphs display the values of user-defined data points. You define a
>   data point in your Vuser script by inserting an lr_user_data_point function at the appropriate place

In pratice I want to use "JSR223 PostProcessor" and via code add values to a time serie. This time serie will be plotted on time based graph. In LR with line of code

> lr_user_data_point ("data_point_1",1);

The UI shows a new data serie on plot that can be used as additional report (generate plot, median, table, etc...).

Thanks
Vincenzo

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be marked as OK and upvoted so that others can use it. Thanks

Comment: Hi
In these days I am looking around to best focus this improvment and maybe open an enhancement as suggested by @UBIKLOADPACK .

As result of my research I have two potential ways :

1. using TestBean framework as described into [link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html#testbean)

2. export the user-defined time-series to Grafana (or similar) using [BackEnd Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at this point there are three possible solution:

1. Open a new feature request as suggested by @UBIKLOADPACK
2. Develop a JMeter plugins using TestBean framework as described into [link](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/DeveloperManual/TestBeanTutorial)
3. Export a time-series to Grafana (or similar) using [BackEnd Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/backend-listener)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such feature in JMeter.

You can request an enhancement but ensure you explain:

- What is the aim of this feature ?
- What benefits it brings

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

**Edit on 3 august 2018:**

- In upcoming JMeter 5.0, it will be possible to graph over time custom variables. See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62166

Comment: There are times where a calculated datapoint has value when the information coming back as part of a timing record is highly variable.  For instance, let's say I am timing bringing back my accounts in a banking environment.  Customer 1 has 2 accounts.  Customer 25 has 50 accounts.  By using datapoint we can get a measure of accounts/time for a normalized measure to take into account the variability which is impacting the timing record

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Another example to enrich this discussion:
I have a service under load with an HTTP Sample that returns a XML body. I want track response time plus the number of occurence of specific tag because its content is dynamic. To track response time I can use usual graphs/table but not for number of observed tag.